# Set another appender in log4net if the first appender fails to log the message

Tags: log4net

I have added an appender to log in SQL Server using log4net, but I want to add the log messages in application event log if there is an error while connecting to database.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="Data Source=PIYUSH-V;initial Catalog=Logs; Integrated Security=True;"/>
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="255"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="50"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="255"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="4000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="2000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
      </parameter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>    
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You'll need to subclass the AdoNetAppender to do that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfloew, Piyush Verma!  You'll get the best answers if you can provide a sample of what you have already tried.

Comment: I am using above configuration file to write log messages in SQL Server and EventLog. 

@stuartd - If I subclass AdoNetAppender, do you mean write my own logic for adding logs in SQL Server, if error log it to event viewer?